# Cant use uuid in nestjs + postgreSQL with backend hosted in railway

Tags: postgresql, migration, nestjs, typeorm

Today i migrate my db from heroku to railway because heroku is no longer free. Everything went perfect, i migrated my db with all the data. I tried getting all the data and its also work fine, the problem is when i try to create for example a new user, im getting a UUID error.

> ERROR [UserService] QueryFailedError: null value in column "id" of relation "user" violates not-null constraint

> uuidv4 is not a function

I tried to solve the issue with `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";` and also updating timescaledb `ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;` but nothing works.

Im using Postgre 14 and typeorm.

Answer (score 1):

The correct function in *uuid-ossp* extension is `uuid_generate_v4()`. However that extension is not required as v14 contains the built in function `gen_random_uuid()` which generates a version 4 uuid. See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i also realised railway only uses postgres V13 you cant choose another version.